# Jquery slider without cloning

Tags: jquery, slider

Is it possible to have a continous/rotational slider with out cloning using jquery? Requirment is onload the half of the 25% of last and previous slide should be shown along with the first/current slide. And when user click on the next/prev button it has to be rotational.

I have tried with cloning, but smaller resolution it is fine, in the bigger resolution even the clonnig div is shown. I should not show the cloning div.

Please suggest me if there are any plugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AnythingSlider

https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider/wiki/Usage

The code which is used for the clone is

```
slider.$items//callback argument
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="MainSliderContent" style="display: table-cell;">
    <div class="Message">
        Test 1
    </div>
    <div class="Message">
        Test 2
    </div>
    <div class="Message">
        test 3
    </div>
    <div class="Message">
        Test 4
    </div>
</div>​


 $(document).ready(function () {
        //if ($('#MainSliderContent').find('div.Message').length > 1) {
        $('#MainSliderContent').find('div.Message:not(:first)').hide();

        $('#MainSliderContent').live({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $(this).addClass('Hover');
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $(this).removeClass('Hover');
            }
        });

        setInterval(function () {
            if (!$('#MainSliderContent').hasClass('Hover')) {
                var $messageObj = $('#MainSliderContent').find('div.Message:visible');
                $messageObj.slideUp('slow').next('div.Message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#MainSliderContent').find('div.Message:last').after($messageObj);
            }
        }, 1 * 1000);
        //}
    });​
```

for demo see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/BJ6R7/

Comment: 1 * 1000 this is for one second u can change it.